# IE8 removing placeholder text after validation fail

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer-8, placeholder, polyfills

Having a similar issue to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152696/placeholders-disapears-after-validation-fails-using-jquery-validate-and-jquery-p)

In all browsers the placeholder text is fine after a validation fail on my form but it disappears in IE8. Initially IE8 wasn't showing the placeholders so I used this fix to fill the placeholders

```
$('[placeholder]')
    .focus(function () {   
        var input = $(this);   
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {  
            input.val('');   
            input.removeClass('placeholder');   
        }   
    })
    .blur(function () {   
        var input = $(this);   
        if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {   
            input.addClass('placeholder');  
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));   
        }  
    })
    .blur();   

$('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function () {    
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {   
        var input = $(this);   
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {   
            input.val('');   
        }  
    })   
});
```

Should I be using a different placeholder fix/polyfill in the first place? or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Better would be to not use placeholder on browser which don't support it. Anyway, using placeholder shouldn't mean you don't have to use some kind of descriptive label to output relative information to user, this is not the goal of placeholder. Think about accessibility

Comment: the design doesn't include labels, got to use placeholders and the go live is this morning

Comment: So my boss would say it is badly designed... You can be disagree of course :)

Comment: I'd agree :) it's a rush job in time for Valentines so not much time for better design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var placeholders = {};
$('form').validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {

   $(form).find(':input[placeholder]').each(function() {
      var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder'); 
      placeholders[placeholder] = this;
      $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
   });       

   form.submit();


 },



enter code here

  $.each(placeholders, function(placeholder, element) {
      $(element).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
  });

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this library for placeholders in browsers that don't support placeholders.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by redefining the default required function of validator, Before calling the validation I added this:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("required", function(value, element, param) {
        // check if dependency is met
        if ( !this.depend(param, element) ) {
            return "dependency-mismatch";
        }
        if ( element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "select" ) {
            // could be an array for select-multiple or a string, both are fine this way
            var val = $(element).val();
            return val && val.length > 0;
        }
        if ( this.checkable(element) ) {
            return this.getLength(value, element) > 0;
        }
        default:
            var placeholderval = $(element).attr('placeholder');
          //if some placeholder values are actually default values, just use "default" attribute to mark them
            var defaultvar = ($(element).attr('default') === undefined);
            return ($.trim(value).length > 0 && ($.trim(value)!=$.trim(placeholderval) || !defaultvar));
    }, jQuery.validator.messages.required);
```